# Windows Phone XAML Designer requires a build to see changes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

After installing the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK, I've seen that the XAML designer of the Windows Phone SDK is not updating when I change a value like the Background property. I need to compile the project to see the modification in the designer. Very painful.

Anyone have an idea? The other XAML designers (Windows 8 store app/WPF) work perfectly, so it seems that it's the SDK's problem.

My configuration:
Haswell i5
Intel HD 4400
4GO Ram
Visual 2012 / 2013 Preview

The problem occurs in both Visual Studio and Blend. Windows 8 Store App and WPF designers work on both IDEs; only the Windows Phone designer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exact problem before. If I'm not mistaken, simply uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, reinstalling the SDK does not change anything :(

Comment: Does the problem occur in both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Yes in VS 2012 and VS 2013. I'm currently formating my pc to install only VS 2012 without addons and I'll reinstall WP 8.0 SDK